# Change sorting function of priority queue during runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, priority-queue

I have a `std::priority_queue` with a custom sorting function. At a point in the program, I want to reorganize the queue using a different function.

Is this possible? Or can I make a pointer to the queue that I can point to a differently sorted queue when needed?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible as the `Compare` function given to the `priority_queue` is a template type, this means that the `Compare` itself belongs to that type.

These:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int>>;
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>>;
```

While looking similar are 2 different types.

What you *can* do is adapt your `Compare` function to look at some external state and sort based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The important part here is to not think of ordered containers like `std::priority_queue` as sorted, because they really aren't. Instead they are, as the name implies, *ordered*. And the ordering is only done by putting new elements in their *ordered* place when they are actually inserted into the container. There's no reordering of the containers.

Therefore it's not really possible to change ordering at run-time, because all the existing elements in the queue will still be ordered the way they were when inserted, and new elements might not be placed in the correct place because the ordering is no longer correct.

The only way to reorder a `std::priority_queue` is to create a new queue with the new ordering function, and then copy the elements from the old to the new queue.

Comment: After the switch, the priority_queue probably won't work properly.

Comment: @user253751 You're right. Completely rewrote my answer.